# Python: Restore Terminal Contents with Curses Like Vim

Tags: python, windows-7, curses

Right now, after my Python program that uses `curses` exits, I'm left with a blank screen. Anything that I'd done prior to running my program is no longer visible.

How can I make it so that after my curses program exits, the prior contents is visible, IE, the way that `less`, `man`, and `vim` do on *nix.

Extra details: I'm using the Windows console, so *nix terminal commands won't work. For anyone wondering how I managed to get `curses` working on Windows, see [my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28368618/901641).

My question is exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044274/how-does-vi-restore-terminal-content-after-quitting-it), except mine is specific to Python (not C) and Windows (not *nix).

Comment: Does `endwin` not work on windows?

Comment: @mjgpy3: I hadn't tested my code outside of Windows yet when I asked. I just did, and I found that it already functions perfectly in *nix. My problem appears to be specific to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

PDCurses attempts to save the screen contents when it starts, and to restore it it you have set the `PDC_RESTORE_SCREEN` environment variable (for Windows, of course).

By *attempts*, I mean that this may fail.  Windows(using the `[ReadConsoleOutput][1]` function) has a 64KB buffer used for this purpose, and large screensizes (especially counting the scrollback) may be too large.  If it cannot save the whole buffer, it tries to save/restore only the part that you see (the "window").  Even that could be too large, of course.

In a quick check of ncurses on the other hand, I do not see this problem (so the problem lies in PDCurses).

From more reading (e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779486/curses-alternative-for-windows)), I see that you are likely using [UniCurses for Python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyunicurses/), which would be more interesting if it were not for the fact that its author chose to license it in a way that precludes its inclusion in any python, ncurses (or PDCurses) release.

Comment: I initially was going to say this didn't work, but it actually kind of did. After my program exists curses, I can scroll up and see all the stuff from before it. But it's as if running curses also inserted a few hundred blank lines. How can I keep it from doing that and restore the screen without all that extra blank space?

Comment: Checking (with lynx, in a console window), I see something like that: it is successfully restoring the visible part of the console buffer, but is blanking the bulk of it--except that a few hundred lines previously, there is some untouched text from a previous run of lynx.  That is with a console buffer which is larger than 64KB, and the behavior is consistent with my caveat above.  If I recall correctly, that's 2 bytes per cell, giving a maxium restorable size of 80x400 (versus the 9999 rows I used).  But limiting the screen also is wrong - seems to be bug...

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for this for now. If you figure out and share how to do it without all those blank lines being inserted I'll make it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`curses.endwin()` should do the trick.

Here's the [documentation explaining it.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.endwin)

Also, here's [where I've personally used this function](https://github.com/mjgpy3/SnakePython/blob/master/mi_snake.py#L127).

Comment: My code ends with (replaced line breaks with ; for readability in comment): `curses.nocbreak(); screen.keypad(0); curses.echo(); curses.endwin()`. After executing that, all that I have on my screen in a brand new Python prompt - nothing is visible before it if I scroll up (the buffer works though - I can hit the up arrow and see anything I had run previously.)

Comment: I hadn't tested my code outside of Windows yet when I asked. I just did, and I found that it already functions perfectly in *nix. My problem appears to be specific to Windows.