# Keeping view of edited file after exiting vim

Tags: vim

When I quit vim, the display reverts to whatever I was seeing before I entered.  On non-vim vi, you keep the vi screen intact except for the bottom line.

Is there an option in vim that allows that latter behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim uses a terminal feature called the *alternate screen* to write its UI there, and restore the original shell contents (where Vim was launched from) on exit. This is controlled by two ANSI escape sequences (see [how does vi restore terminal content after quitting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044274/how-does-vi-restore-terminal-content-after-quitting-it)).

You can disable that from within Vim by clearing the corresponding terminal settings. Put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set t_ti= t_te=
```

Alternatively, you could also disable this capability in the terminal; at least the multiplexers `screen` and `tmux` allow this. See [Prevent Applications Like Vim and Less Clearing Screen on Exit](http://chenyufei.info/blog/2011-12-15/prevent-vim-less-clear-screen-on-exit/) for details.

Comment: Alternatively (if you are using xterm), you can disable it using a menu entry.  I do not recall seeing this feature in other terminals.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for, just paste the below commands in your .vimrc. I got it from some where in the net.

```
" Return to last edit position when opening files
  autocmd BufReadPost *
       \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
       \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
       \ endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is on opening a file in vim.  I'm looking to change behaviour when I **close** a file.